# How to insert title inside react-select above selected option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to add static title to react-select that will appear above my current selected options.

[image]

How it can be done with react-select ?

thank you :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you trying to do Tooltip on your current selecrtion

Comment: no
i am trying keep my placeholder even after option has been selected

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for InputLabel (Material-UI equivalent).

In react-select there is an option to add label with *placeholder* prop. It only shows on top, when you have selected something from dropdown, but I think it is a good start.

Have a look at the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/6x9405rlqk

> Placeholder Component to be displayed in the input when nothing is
>   selected. By default it is the text 'Select...' See props docs for
>   more details:
>   https://react-select.com/props#select-props

Comment: hi thank you for answering
but i want to keep the title inside the react-select borders

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a floating label is what you're looking for. A "placeholder" is meant to disappear when an actual input is entered so trying to make the placeholder work as a label would be counter-intuitive.

[image]

You can add a floating label to react-select by adding a label to a custom control component:

```
// CustomControl.tsx

import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { components } from "react-select";

export const Control = (props: any) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Label isFloating={props.isFocused || props.hasValue}>Select</Label>
      <components.Control {...props} />
    </>
  );
};

const Label = styled.label<{ isFloating?: boolean }>`
  left: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s ease all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease all;

  top: ${(props) => (props.isFloating ? `5px` : `35%`)};
  font-size: ${(props) => (props.isFloating ? `0.5rem` : `1rem`)};
`;
```

Then just add this custom control component to Select:

```
<Select 
  ...
  components={{ Control }} 
  placeholder=""
/>
```

[Live demo](https://www.absingh.com/react-select-custom/) | [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4221)